# Ab eo abeo ; In clino inclino Are there other jingles of this form?

Tags: ambiguity, grammarians, word-play

Quintilian told his students to watch out for ambiguity where two words could be heard as one. Medieval writers seem to have enjoyed such word-play.

Are there other examples like these either written or pictured?

> ***Ab eo abeo*** I go from there.
>   ***In clino inclino*** I lean forward in bed

Comment: Outside of rhetorical treatises, J. N. Adams [mentions](https://books.google.com/books?id=GDP9VHGbF1AC&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q&f=false) a bunch in relation to obscenity.

Comment: Coincidentally, I mentioned one here a few days ago: http://latin.stackexchange.com/a/2871/1289

Comment: @blagae -valued quotation of "invita remansit in vita" = She remained unwillingly alive   (Apuleius, Met. VIII, 6) pending complete answer.